# How do I change the background color of a plot made with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

By default, ggplot2 produces plots with a grey background.  How do I change the color of the background of the plot?

For example, a plot produced by the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
myplot<-ggplot(data=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,4)), aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_line()
myplot
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

To change the panel's background color, use the following code:

```
myplot + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'green', colour = 'red'))
```

To change the color of the plot (but not the color of the panel), you can do:

```
myplot + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'green', colour = 'red'))
```

See here for more theme details [Quick reference sheet for legends, axes and themes](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/1f4c1e628f25081).

Comment: There also is the `theme_bw`, giving you a white background and grey gridlines. I use it all the time, as in print it looks much better than the default grey background: `myplot + theme_bw()`

Comment: @ROLO: Nice! Is there a way to apply this to all plots by default?

Comment: Put this at the beginning of your script for default B&W ggplots: 
`ggplot <- function(...) {
 ggplot2::ggplot(...) + theme_bw()
}`

Comment: @ROLO that deserves it's own answer, especially because Jack's answer doesn't change the colour of the grid lines.

Comment: Note that `opts` and `theme_rect` are deprecated in the newer versions of ggplot2. (0.9.3). So the newer version of the second command would become: `myplot + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill='green', colour='red'))`

Answer (score 58):

To avoid deprecated `opts` and `theme_rect` use:

```
myplot + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='green', colour='red'))
```

To define your own custom theme, based on theme_gray but with some of your changes and a few added extras including control of gridline colour/size (more options available to play with [at ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html)):

```
theme_jack <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
    theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
        theme(
            axis.text = element_text(colour = "white"),
            axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "pink", size=rel(3)),
            axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "blue", angle=45),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill="green"),
            panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(size=3),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "orange"),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill="red")
    )   
}
```

To make your custom theme the default when ggplot is called in future, without masking:

```
theme_set(theme_jack())
```

If you want to change an element of the currently set theme:

```
theme_update(plot.background = element_rect(fill="pink"), axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

To store the current default theme as an object:

```
theme_pink <- theme_get()
```

Note that `theme_pink` is a list whereas `theme_jack` was a function. So to return the theme to theme_jack use `theme_set(theme_jack())` whereas to return to theme_pink use `theme_set(theme_pink)`.

You can replace `theme_gray` by `theme_bw` in the definition of `theme_jack` if you prefer. For your custom theme to resemble `theme_bw` but with all gridlines (x, y, major and minor) turned off:

```
theme_nogrid <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
    theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
        theme(
            panel.grid = element_blank()
    )   
}
```

Finally a more radical theme useful when plotting [choropleths](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html) or other maps in ggplot, based on discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/ckA8aZe3nDs) but updated to avoid deprecation. The aim here is to remove the gray background, and any other features that might distract from the map.

```
theme_map <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
    theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
        theme(
            axis.line=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3, "lines"),
            axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "lines"),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA),
            legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"),
            legend.key.size=unit(1.2, "lines"),
            legend.position="right",
            legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
            legend.title=element_text(size=rel(0.8), face="bold", hjust=0),
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            panel.border=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
            plot.background=element_blank(),
            plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
            plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
            strip.background=element_rect(fill="grey90", colour="grey50"),
            strip.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
            strip.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.8), angle=-90) 
        )   
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.  FYI, I have found the argument `plot.background` must be passed to `theme`. The other arguments are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom theme to make the ggplot2 background white and a bunch of other changes that's good for publications and posters. Just tack on +mytheme. If you want to add or change options by +theme after +mytheme, it will just replace those options from +mytheme.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_cowplot())

mytheme = list(
    theme_classic()+
        theme(panel.background = element_blank(),strip.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill=NA),panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
              legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position="bottom", strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=9),
              axis.text=element_text(face="bold"),axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5,size=13))
)

ggplot(data=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,4)), aes(x=a, y=b)) + mytheme + geom_line()
```

[image: custom ggplot theme]