# How to set the background color of a plot blank?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm thinking is it possible to change the background color of plot using ggplot2?like white or something else? instead of the color in the following

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736378/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2
I think this is a duplicate question

Comment: try adding `+ theme_bw()` it's much nicer than the nasty grey.  For more builtin themes just go into your editor, write `theme` and get it to autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the panel's background color, use the following code:

```
myplot + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'green', colour = 'red'))
```

To change the color of the plot (but not the color of the panel), you can do:

```
myplot + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'green', colour = 'red'))
```

See here for more theme details https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/AfTB5ijyUIE